# Javascript Regex returns null, node.js

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I try to select a string based on regex, I use node.js ,here is my code :

```
var string = ' emaild@d.com    Tel:   +971000000000 0500000348';
var regExp = '\\(\\+971\\|00971\\|05\\)\\d\\{1,12\\}';
var find = string.match(regExp)[0];
console.log(find);
```

I need to select only numbers that starts with +971 , 00971, 05 , this returns null, (I had to escape twice coz it throws an error if I don't) 
this regex works fine: `'\\+971\\d{1,12}';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know node.js specific, so sorry if my answer would be stupid, but what about:

```js
var string = ' emaild@d.com    Tel:   +971000000000 0500000348';
var regExp = /(\+971|00971|05)\d{1,12}/g;
var find = string.match(regExp);
return find;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
(\+971|00971|05)(\d{1,12})
```

Get group 2 and you should get what you want. I am not sure why you need to escape also. It is working for me without escaping.